# How can I have permission to call a remote stored-proc, but not save the results?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
USE [MyDB]

GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'1.2.3.4\SQL2014', @useself = 'FALSE', @rmtuser = 'Client', @rmtpassword = 'Password';  
GO  

--insert into TravelData
EXEC [1.2.3.4\SQL2014].[TravelDB].[schema1].[GetTravelData]  1, '28-Nov-2016 16:00', '28-Nov-2016 19:00'

GO
```

This query works fine, I see the results of the remote server stored proc call listed in Visual Studio. If I uncomment the `INSERT INTO` line I get errors:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "1.2.3.4\SQL2014"
>   returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its
>   support for remote/network transactions.". The operation could not be
>   performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server
>   "1.2.3.4\SQL2014" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

I'm a coder not a DBA... are the security permissions that granular that I'm allowed to call a `procedure` but not do anything with the data and I just need to ask their DBA to tweak the settings? Or is this error potentially masking something else? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You must enable **distributed transactions** features on your DB server.

You can see this [**guide**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlforum/2010/12/20/faq-how-do-i-configure-sql-server-to-enable-distributed-transactions-via-linked-server/)

Comment: Presumably you mean they must be enabled on the remote server i.e. it's not something I can do, I need their admin/DBA to enable it?

Comment: @Mr.Boy:you can't do this,the admin of the server in question should do this

Answer (score 1):

Your server is attempting to promote a local transaction (the insert into `TravelData`) to a [distributed transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188386.aspx) with the remote server - because the command involves resources from both servers - but the remote server won't allow this to happen.

You should be able to prevent this behaviour by setting the "Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions" property of the `[1.2.3.4\SQL2014]` linked server to `false`.

You can do this through T-SQL with the following command:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
  @server=N'1.2.3.4\SQL2014', 
  @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', 
  @optvalue=N'false'
```

Comment: I don't know what this means (educated guess: it's an optimisation where the transaction is combined into one unit which is sent to the remote server) but it seems to work

Comment: @Mr.Boy - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188386.aspx for a description of distributed transactions.

Comment: @Mr.Boy - I added a bit more explanation of what's happening.